# Ingesting data from an API and webactivity

Tags: azure-data-factory, pipeline, data-ingestion

I need to ingest data from 3 endpoints.
my pipeline is as follows:
a web activity to obtain authentication to the api via a post request and 3 web activities to retrieve the data via a get request.
I would need to ingest data from these 3 web activities  to a location in the raw zone .
How can I achieve this?

[image: pipeline with three endpoints]

I have managed to make the API calls and get a response. But have no knowledge on how to proceed further

Comment: Where you want to store this data , what is your sink?

Comment: I would like to store this in ADLS.

Comment: In which file format and data of all three files in a sinle file or different files?

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, you're getting the file contents or file from the web activities?

Comment: file content from web activity

Comment: I would like to save the endpoints in 3 separate files. JSON format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use copy activity with [Http connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http?tabs=data-factory) to call your endpoints. and add it as source and the select appropriate sink. and copy the data

- sample liked service:

[image]

- Source example

[image]

**OR**

- Use copy activity with a sample .csv file with one column as the source dataset . Add additional column and provide a new column named  `Webactvityoutput`  with value =  `@string(activity('Web1').output)`  .
  [image]
- In the sink, use another dataset with delimited text and pass file name as with `.json` extension. set **Escape character** as `No escape character` and **Quote character** as `No quote character`.
  [image]
- In the mapping tab, click on Import schema and delete the column from dummy file and only keep the additionally added column.
  [image]
- Execute the pipeline and check if the webActivity output got stored in the .json in the ADLS
  [image]

Comment: Hi @Pratik Lad . If you notice I have a web activity to authenticate the post request to the client API. If I choose to use a HTTP connector, can I configure settings for username and password from azure key vault ? In short if I go with this method which activity can I configure to replace my 'auth_request' activity?

Comment: Used the HTTP connector. Authentication was basic. I added the cookie obtained from the authorize activity into the additional headers section. Thanks @Pratik Lad